# Can you have two stable equilibria only in a positive polynomial ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Let
$$
\dot x=f(x)
$$ be a polynomial ode that has three equilibria. Moreover

- note $x$ is an $n$ dimensional vector,
- assume that the positive orthant is forward invariant (recall that the positive orthant is the subset of $\Bbb R^n$ where all the coordinates are positive).

**Question**. Can you have two positive stable equilibria and one ustable outside the positive orthant?
(Remember that we say that an equilibrium is positive if it belongs to the positive orthant)

In general, can you have only two positive equilibria?

Comment: Consecutive equilibria cannot be both stable or both unstable.

Comment: What is the "positive orthant"?

Comment: @Paul sorry I didnt explain that x is a vector

Comment: @RobertLewis the positive orthant is the subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ where all the coordinates are positive

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Equilibrium points have to always switch between positive and negative. You can easily see this if you choose an ODE in a single variable. As for an equilibrium $f(x)=0$, you can see for the single variable case that each time you have a stable equilibrium, you have crossed the $x$-axis and thus the next equilibrium needs to be unstable. This generalizes to multiple variables. A corner case is, if $f(x)$ only touches the $x$-axis (i.e. $f'(x)=0$ at the equilibrium), but then you have one side where the equilibrium is stable and the other side where it's unstable. Strogatz' book "Nonlinear dynamics and chaos" has nice and intuitive explanations of these properties in the first chapter.

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain that x is a vector. By a positive equilibrium I mean that it belongs to the positive orthant